# Why do Chrome mousemove event does not work properly when an SVG element is scaled by CSS transform?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, svg

I created an SVG map and scaled to about 400x and when I hover (mousemove event) to a tiny element the event does not fire sometimes. I believe the coordinates system is stretched too and limited to 1px and can't accommodate float pixel value?

If you need more details, feel free to ask.

Here is a video detail to explain it more: [**Link to Video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3gV6iYapANE)

Here is a demo [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2uyhe7f5/3/)
just scroll the Result down to see the demo.

And here's my code:

**HTML**:

```
<div style="transform: scale(1000); transform-origin: top left; vertical-align: top;">
  <svg width="0.5" height="0.5">
  </svg>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
$(window).ready(function() {

var divisor = 200;

  var x = 50;
  var y = 50;
  for (var iX = 0; iX < x; iX++) {
    for (var iY = 0; iY < y; iY++) {
      var obj = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
      obj.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", (iX / divisor) * 2);
      obj.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", (iY / divisor) * 2);
      obj.setAttributeNS(null, "r", (1 / divisor));
      obj.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "red");
      $("svg")[0].appendChild(obj);
    }
  }
  $('svg circle').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).data('dt-fill', $(this).attr('fill'))
      .attr('fill', 'black');
  }).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).attr('fill', $(this).data('dt-fill'));
  });
});
```

As you could observe in *JSFiddle* (on Chrome), the hover event skips some circles.

> Note: In other browsers it works properly.

Comment: [**A minimal example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: JSFiddle demo added.

Comment: Wow... I don't think I've ever seen a question with a video. Mad props!

Comment: @JesKeshlyCruz where is mousemove event you are using?

Comment: http://depth-first.com/articles/2010/12/03/the-mysterious-google-chrome-svg-bug/

Comment: @Adnan I used mouseenter instead on the demo, same idea all mouse events that plot x and y.

Comment: @Robert Longson
Great feedback. I think this is the one.

Comment: @Robert Longson, could you put that in answers so that I could rate it up.

Comment: It's not suitable as an answer: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info if you want to write up something yourself as an answer, feel free.